# GET request using Gson (java)

Tags: java, json, get, gson

I'm pretty sure I'm close to getting this right....

I'm making a request to this url: "http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip?format=json" (at http://svc.metrotransit.org/)
and the output format looks like so:

```
[{
"Description":"String content",
"ProviderID":"String content",
"Route":"String content"
}]
```

With the below code I currently have, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException when executing the line:

```
JsonElement element = jp.parse(new 
InputStreamReader((InputStream)request.getContent()));
```

- obviously something is off since I'm not experienced in web requests whatsoever but I'm really not sure what.
Essentially, all I want to get is the string content of the "route" element but I'm not quite sure if I'm properly doing that (say if my code actually compiles).

```
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection request;
    try
    {
        url = new URL("http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip?format=json");
        request = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        request.setDoOutput(true);
        request.setRequestMethod("GET");

        request.connect();
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement element = jp.parse(new 
InputStreamReader((InputStream)request.getContent()));
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();

        String routeID = null;
        if (request.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            //parse json object
            routeID = obj.get("Route").getAsString();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: why do you think that `request.getContent()` will be of type `InputStream` ?

Comment: @Runesr4nerds what exactly is the error

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
request.getInputStream()
```

instead of

```
(InputStream)request.getContent()
```

and remember that, if response code not 2xx (like 200, 201) you must use `request.getErrorStream()`

Answer (score 1):

I checked your URL http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip?format=json directly in browser, it responsed FileNotFound also.

So, my suggestions are:

1. please re-check the URL
2. you should use request.getInputStream() instead of getContent()
3. you may need to change `JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject()` to `JsonArray obj = element.getAsJsonArray()` because the response is not a JsonObject, it is a array

Comment: try to use http://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/Stops/21/3?format=json for testing